# CarouselView.Content is empty

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I try study is new componet CarouselView and с# in total.
But I have problem.
This code display is empty content in CarouselView. Why?
I send is fill code my colutions.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:carousel="clr-namespace:CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions;assembly=CarouselView.FormsPlugin.Abstractions"   
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:App6"
             x:Class="App6.MainPage">
    <StackLayout>
        <Image Source="home.png"/>
        <carousel:CarouselViewControl x:Name="MyCV" BackgroundColor="Black">
            <carousel:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Label Text="{Binding TestLine}"></Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </carousel:CarouselViewControl.ItemTemplate>
        </carousel:CarouselViewControl>         
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>


namespace App6
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        class CustomCell
        {
            public string TestLine { get; set; }
        }

        public MainPage()
        {      
            InitializeComponent();

            List<CustomCell> myCarousel = new List<CustomCell>();
            myCarousel.Add(new CustomCell { TestLine = "Line 1" });
            myCarousel.Add(new CustomCell { TestLine = "Line 2" });
            MyCV.ItemsSource = myCarousel;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I take out create list in property public IEnumerable  MyList

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct, so your problem is in the visual layer. Try to define the height and width wherever possible and it should resolve the problem. CarouselView isn't the official control and isn't up to standards of Xamarin's built-in controls so it has some somewhat unexpected behaviors like this.

Comment: Thank you. I added VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" and my line is displayded.

Comment: It is encouraged according to site rules to vote and mark answer as accepted and discouraged to say 'thank you'.